# How to set boolean value as empty when value is not there in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql query in which I am applying case condition for a boolean, int and date but it is throwing error when i add else '', is there a way to add empty value.

```
select case when isActive then 'Y' else '' end as active,
case when id is not null else '' end as id,
case when createdDt is not null else '' end dt from table
```

can anyone help me in this.

Comment: "when id is not null else" Where is the "then"-part in your CASE statement? By the way, using CamelCase in SQL won't work, everything is handled in PostgreSQL as lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax error in your `CASE` expression, you cannot use an empty string as boolean value. `boolean` only has the three values `TRUE`, `FALSE` and NULL. Perhaps you could use the latter value, which means “unknown”.